# Git sync same branch in two repositories which are cloned from same master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I am trying to implement Git in my company. I decided to implement this model http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

There are three branches in main repo, ie master,develop and feature1. There are two developer named Alice and Bob. Both developers are working on the clone of main repo. Both of them working in feature1 branch. Alice has defined a Git remote, named bob, pointing to Bob’s repository, and vice versa.

How can i make get Bobs changes on feature branch to Alice and vice versa?

Comment: Are you trolling? Are you trying to implement git in your company without reading the git basics even from the most basic random git tutorial on internet? Just teach them how to `git push` and `git pull`

Comment: I am using git push and pull with main repo. My question is about using it with  remote repos, ie use to user push and pull operations

Comment: Your "main repo" (usually "origin") is a "remote repo" too. They are all managed with `git remote` you just need to specify to `git pull/push` which repo you want to work on. You really need to invest some time learning the basics, you can't just ninja into git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[A successful Git branching model » nvie.com](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)" comes with a set of tools called "[git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)" on top of your default git installation.

This utility provide [some interesting commands](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments) to deal with features. Thus Bob or Alice or anyone else can create a new feature and publish it to the main repository:

```
git flow feature start <name>
git flow feature publish <name>
```

Then Bob and Alice have to track and pull the newly created feature:

```
git flow feature track <name>
git flow feature pull <remote> [<name>]
```

And then Bob and Alice can use everyday git basics to pull (resp. push) changes from (resp. to) the main repository.

Once the feature is finished you have to tell it to git-flow and delete the feature branch from the main repository:

```
git flow feature finish <name>
git push origin :<name>
```